# Hibernate EAGER fetching

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Hi I have a scenario where I need to load the third level domain object while loading the records from the database.
 Here is the example of my senario:
There are three domain class USER, PROPERTY,CONTACT

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class USER{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name = "id")
     private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PROP_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Property property;
    ............
    other fields and getter and setter methdos
    .............
   }

   @Entity
   @Table(name="properties")
   public class Property{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

       @OneToOne(mappedBy="property", fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
       @JoinColumn(name="CONTACT_ID")
       private Contact contact;
       ............
       other fields and getter and setter methdos
       .............
   }

 @Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "ADDRESS1",length = 255)
private String address1;
@Column(name = "ADDRESS2",length = 255)
private String address2;
     ............
       other fields and getter and setter methdos
       .............
   }
```

There are my domain classes and I am trying to get Contact details when I fetch the USER record. 
I am able to get the Property record by using JOIN fetch mode but I am not getting how can i get the third level record.

Here is my query for reference:

```
        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(USER.class);
        criteria.setFetchMode("property", FetchMode.JOIN);
        List<USER> users = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

Here I am able to get the property object as I am doing the JOIN query.
But I want the Contact Object too along with the Property object.

Please not I am not allowed to use the EAFER fetch definition for complete domain itself.
Somehow I have to do in criteria itself.

That means I am not allowed to define Property table something like this:

```
@Entity
   @Table(name="properties")
   public class Property{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

       @OneToOne(mappedBy="property", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinColumn(name="CONTACT_ID")
       private Contact contact;
       ............
       other fields and getter and setter methdos
       .............
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding another fetchmode for `property.contact` ?

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(USER.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("property", FetchMode.JOIN)
criteria.setFetchMode("property.contact", FetchMode.JOIN);
List<USER> users = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```